# Getting ambiguous reference to member subscript

Tags: swift3

I am updating my code to swift3.0 but getting ambiguous refrence to member? What wrong i might be doing. Here is the method I am getting error in.

```
 open class func parseJsonTenantList(_ list: [NSDictionary]?, strElementName: String, attrName1: String, attrNameValue2: String) -> [TenantRegister]
{
    var renantList: [TenantRegister] = []
    var key: String?
    if let dict : [NSDictionary] = list {
        var value: String?
        for i in 0..<dict.count {
            ///  if attribute name doesn't match then it returns nil
            if  let s1: AnyObject = dict[i].value(forKey: attrName1)
            {
                key = s1 as? String
            }
            if  let s2: AnyObject = dict[i].value(forKey: attrNameValue2)
            {
                value = s2 as? String
            }
            if (!(String.stringIsNilOrEmpty(value) && String.stringIsNilOrEmpty(key)))
            {
                let t: TenantRegister = TenantRegister()
                t.name = key
                t.tenantId = Guid(value!)
                renantList.append(t)
            }
        }
    }



    return renantList
}
```

Comment: Getting Error at this Line :             if  let s1: AnyObject = dict[i].value(forKey: attrName1)

Comment: Is you issue solved?

Comment: No,still no idea what to do

Comment: Ok let me put solution then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using `NSDictionary`, to solved your problem simply cast the list to Swift's native type `[[String:Any]]` and then use subscript with it instead of `value(forKey:)`

```
if let dict = list as? [[String:Any]] {
    var value: String?
    for i in 0..<dict.count {
        ///  if attribute name doesn't match then it returns nil
        if  let s1 = dict[i][attrName1] as? String
        {
            key = s1
        }
        if  let s2 = dict[i][attrNameValue2] as? String
        {
            value = s2
        }
        if (!(String.stringIsNilOrEmpty(value) && String.stringIsNilOrEmpty(key)))
        {
            let t: TenantRegister = TenantRegister()
            t.name = key
            t.tenantId = Guid(value!)
            renantList.append(t)
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift use native type Dictionary `[:]` and Array `[]` instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` to overcome this type of issues.